# XPath with regex match on an attribute value

Tags: regex, xpath, attributes

I've searched and tinkered around for hours in an effort to crack this one, but I'm still having problems. I have the XML data below:

```
<game id="2009/05/02/arimlb-milmlb-1" pk="244539">
  <team id="109" name="Arizona" home_team="false">
    <event number="9" inning="1" description="Felipe Lopez doubles to left fielder Chris Duffy.  "/>
    <event number="15" inning="1" description="Augie Ojeda flies out to center fielder Mike Cameron.  "/>
    <event number="23" inning="1" description="Chad Tracy doubles to right fielder Joe Sanchez.  "/>
    <event number="52" inning="2" description="Mark Reynolds lines out to left fielder Chris Duffy.  "/>
    <!-- more data here -->
  </team>
</game>
```

I'm trying to get the total number of event nodes that contain the text ' doubles ' in the value of the description attribute. This is what I've been trying so far, to no avail (irb throws an error):

```
"/game/team/event/@description[matches(.,' doubles ')]"
```

Since I'm just trying to match a fragment of the value of the description attribute, it's possible to use the XPath 2.0 function 'matches', right? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mikecito - I'm using Java 1.6, but I also use Ruby irb for development and debugging purposes with stuff like XPath. That is, I was trying to scan the file using XPath in irb first, and once I had an XPath that got what I wanted, I would transfer it over to my Java code.

Comment: Dimitre - The XPath you listed ended up working great. I'll leave a separate comment below your posting.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the total number of
>   event nodes that contain the text '
>   doubles ' in the value of the
>   description attribute.

**[`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) is a standard XPath 2.0 function. It is not available in XPath 1.0**.

**You can use**:

```
count(/*/*/event[contains(@description, ' doubles ')])
```

**To verify this**, here is a small XSLT transformation which just outputs the result of evaluating the above XPath expression on the provided XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "count(/*/*/event[contains(@description, ' doubles ')])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<game id="2009/05/02/arimlb-milmlb-1" pk="244539">
    <team id="109" name="Arizona" home_team="false">
        <event number="9" inning="1" description="Felipe Lopez doubles to left fielder Chris Duffy.  "/>
        <event number="15" inning="1" description="Augie Ojeda flies out to center fielder Mike Cameron.  "/>
        <event number="23" inning="1" description="Chad Tracy doubles to right fielder Joe Sanchez.  "/>
        <event number="52" inning="2" description="Mark Reynolds lines out to left fielder Chris Duffy.  "/>
        <!-- more data here -->
    </team>
</game>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2
```

Comment: Dimitre - As I mentioned above, the XPath in your posting worked great. I ended up making it more specific with the following:

`"count(/game/team[@home_team='false']/event[contains(@description, ' doubles ')])"`

Thanks very much for your help! I really appreciate it.

And Java 1.6 doesn't speak XPath 2.0, apparently.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following variants:

```
/game/team/event[matches(@description, ' doubles ')]/@description

/game/team/event[matches(@description, '^.*?doubles.*$')]/@description

/game/team/event[contains(@description, ' doubles ')]/@description
```

Comment: The first two didn't work when I tried them in Java 1.6, I suspect because XPath 2.0 apparently isn't available. The third one didn't cause any exception, but it didn't appear to map to the desired nodes -- the answer that came back was NaN. But thanks very much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I'm just trying to match a
>   fragment of the value of the
>   description attribute, it's possible
>   to use the XPath 2.0 function
>   'matches', right?

**Yes, as long as you are using an XPath 2.0 engine to evaluate the XPath expression.**

If you were to execute that XPath using an XPath 2.0 engine, it would select the appropriate `@description` attributes.

> If so, what am I doing wrong?

If you are using an XPath 2.0 engine, your issue may be that you have selected a sequence of nodes, but are expecting the count.

**If you want to return the count of those attributes, you could use the `count()` function:**

```
count(/game/team/event/@description[matches(.,' doubles ')])
```

Comment: The matches() function doesn't appear to be available in Java 1.6 (not that I really knew that beforehand) -- it throws an XPathExpressionException. But thanks anyway! I appreciate it.

Comment: The standard Java 1.6 libraries don't support XPath 2.0, but Saxon and PsychoPath do.