# Space in PHP xpath query (new SimpleXMLElement)

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I receive a XML output and I convert it with new SimpleXMLElement.
The output is an array. So the XML element is $xml.

```
print_r($xml->xpath('categories[categories_name="Toners"]/childs/categories[categories_name="Color LaserJet"]'));
```

In the second [categories_name], the value has a space in the string. There goes something wrong because of the space. I don't get any information returned, if I delete the value with another existing value without a space, I get the information I want.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you include the actual XML that is causing the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you need REGEX to perform a looser match, see [XPath with regex match on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925567/xpath-with-regex-match-on-an-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the question to a small reproducible example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<books>
  <book><title>A Title</title></book>
  <book><title>  A Title  </title></book>  
</books>
XML;
$books = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo  "String compare:\n";
foreach ($books->xpath('//book[title="A Title"]') as $book) {
  var_dump((string)$book->title);
}
```

Output:

```
String compare: 
string(7) "A Title"
```

The second book title contains preceding and following whitespaces, so a simple string compare will not match it. One way to solve that is to use `normalize-space()`. This Xpath function will replace any sequence of whitespaces with a single space and remove preceding/following whitespaces. It does a little to much but for the most cases it should not matter.

```
echo  "\nwith normalize-space():\n";
foreach ($books->xpath('//book[normalize-space(title)="A Title"]') as $book) {
  var_dump((string)$book->title);
}
```

Output:

```
with normalize-space(): 
string(7) "A Title" 
string(11) " A Title "
```

Now it matches both titles, but it will match something like `A      Title` as well.

Another solution allows you more control, but requires DOM. In DOM you can register PHP functions to be callable from XPath expressions. This can be existing functions or your own. You can make `trim()` available:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions(['trim']);

echo  "\nCall back into PHP:\n";
$expression = '//book[php:functionString("trim", string(title)) = "A Title"]';
foreach($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node));
}
```

With you own callback function you could do anything like RegEx matches or unicode string transliterations.