# Get elements with style value greater than threshold with XPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, lxml

So, in a nutshell, given the following html (Extra asterisk marks are my own addition):

```
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; **left:66px;** top:1892px; width:91px; height:10px;">
    <span style="font-family: Times-Roman; font-size:10px">FOO  
    <br>
    </span>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; **left:514px;** top:1892px; width:20px; height:10px;">
    <span style="font-family: Times-Roman; font-size:10px">BAR
    <br>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to leverage X-Path to get all the nodes which have the `left` attribute less than a threshold, and get all the nodes which have the `left` attribute greeter than a given threshold, something such as this: `/div[@style("left") < 300]`.

Looking around this doesn't seem to be possible, the closest I have managed to find was something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925567/xpath-with-regex-match-on-an-attribute-value), however I would like to avoid using regular expressions to match numerical data since the threshold can vary.

I am trying to extract this information through Python (`lxml` module). Basically I have a pdf with columns on the left and on the right, and I want to separate the page into 2 (get all the content on the left on its own, and all the content on the right on its own).

Comment: _Looking around this doesn't seem to be possible_ I'm confused, what is your question, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import lxml.html
foo = """
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:66px; top:1892px; width:91px; height:10px;">
    <span style="font-family: Times-Roman; font-size:10px">FOO  
    <br>
    </span>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:514px; top:1892px; width:20px; height:10px;">
    <span style="font-family: Times-Roman; font-size:10px">BAR
    <br>
    </span>
</div> """

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(foo)
doc.xpath("//div[number(substring-before(substring-after(@style, 'left:'),'px;')) < 300]")[0]
```

This selects the first `<div>`.